# Mongodb create pseudo fields?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoskin

Hello I'd like to know if it's possible to create pseudo properties on Mondodb. This is, currently I have a collections users like this:

```
{_id: (_1), name: "user1", secret: "1"}
{_id: (_2), name: "user2", secret: "2"}
```

When I query the database. I do something like:

```
function getuser(objectId) {
  db.users.find({_id : objectId}).toArray(function(err, result) {
    x = result[0];
    x.pseudoField1 = hash(secret); 
    return x;
  });
}
```

Then I do some operations on the `x` object, and return to put on the database, but before I have to filter the not needed properties, so I do:

```
y = {}
y._id = x._id
y.name = x.name
y.secret = x.secret
db.users.update({_id: y._id}, y);
```

What I'd like to do is know if there is any way to make the databse automaticaly return an object with the `pseudoField1` with the function I want, and furthermore, when I issue an update with `x`, only the fields `_id`, `name` and `secret` get updated.

Comment: How about implementing this logic in a custom function and then only using that function as a proxy for your collection's update/insert/find methods?

Comment: if you are using mongoose.. use virtuals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to calculate fields on the database, you can use an aggregation pipeline with a [$project](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage. The aggregation frameworks offers [some simple arithmetic operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-arithmetic/) to create fields which are derived from values of other fields, but implementing a complex hash function is likely far too complicated to do on the database.

Your second requirement - telling MongoDB to ignore a certain field when inserting - isn't possible out-of-the-box. But what you can do is [remove the field from the document before saving it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-to-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object). You can also use an object-document wrapper like Mongoose which allows you to define schemas and exclude certain fields from storing them in the database.